# Does removing just last bit from output of one way function change its one wayness?

Tags: one-way-function

If $g(x)$ if length preserving one way function, is there a scenario where  $h(x) := g(x)_{1\ldots |x|−1}$ . I.e., $h$ returns all bits that g returns, except for the last bit., is not a one way function.

I think it has to be one way because the probability of inverse just doubles at most. If the probability of inverse is negligible already in case of one way function $g(x)$, how can removing last bit change its behavior?

Comment: Use the contra-positive argument to make it more clear.

Comment: Suggestion: add the formal definition of OWF that you are using. That will clarify.